# edit texts from text view into edit text in android

Tags: android

I do not know what is really happening for my EditText!

I have a TextView, an EdiText and a Button.

The logic needed is:
Sets the EditText with the content of the TextView when clicking the button. 
After "Done" is clicked, the TextView will display the content of the EditText.

This is my code so far:

```
        speech_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speech);
        speech_text_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.speech_edit);
        editBTN= (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        editBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            speech_text_edit.setText(speech_text.getText().toString());
            speech_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            speech_text_edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //open keyboard
            InputMethodManager show_imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            show_imm.showSoftInput(editBTN, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            speech_text_edit.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                      speech_text.setText(speech_text_edit.getText().toString());
                        speech_text_edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        speech_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        speech_text_edit.setFocusable(false);

                        //close keyboard
                        InputMethodManager hide_imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        hide_imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editBTN.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Layout code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/speech"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_margin="25dp" android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:textSize="25sp" android:textAlignment="inherit"
    android:background="@drawable/curved_background"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:padding="10dp" android:visibility="visible"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:id="@+id/speech_edit"
    android:background="@drawable/curved_background"
    android:imeActionLabel="actionDone"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_margin="25dp" android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:focusable="true"/>
```

My problems are:

1. Only works once! After that there is no keyboard nor pointer.
2. EditText shows texts just in one line at the center. why?

Thanks for your help.

this is logCats:

```
05-14 19:26:45.045 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper 

D/SensorManager: unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@4215f0c8
05-14 19:26:45.045 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper D/Sensors: Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
05-14 19:26:45.045 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper I/Sensors: sendDelay --- 200000000
05-14 19:26:45.045 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper D/SensorManager: JNI - sendDelay
05-14 19:26:45.045 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper I/SensorManager: Set normal delay = true
05-14 19:26:45.045 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper D/SensorManager: registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@4215de80
05-14 19:26:45.050 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
05-14 19:26:45.065 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
05-14 19:26:45.080 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
05-14 19:26:45.080 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
05-14 19:26:45.080 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
05-14 19:26:45.100 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
05-14 19:26:45.100 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper W/IInputConnectionWrapper: setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
05-14 19:26:45.100 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
05-14 19:27:01.140 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper D/SensorManager: unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@4215de80
05-14 19:27:01.140 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper D/Sensors: Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
05-14 19:27:01.140 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper I/Sensors: sendDelay --- 200000000
05-14 19:27:01.140 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper D/SensorManager: JNI - sendDelay
05-14 19:27:01.140 15484-15484/type_helper.maxsoft.com.typehelper I/SensorManager: Set normal delay = true
```

Comment: Your logcat has no errors, so I'm not sure what you are trying to show

Comment: ok, i explain again. "Hello" is writen in T.V. . editBTN is clicked. E.T. show "Hello" with keyboard and pointer. i edit it to "Hello world" . Done BTN is clicked, T.V. shows "Hello world" . its ok. now time i click editBTN again. E.T. shows "Hello world" too, but soft-keyboard and pointer are not show/start.

Comment: the `setFocusable(false)` prevent you from entering the edit text again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

```
TextView#setFocusable(true);
TextView#requestFocus();
```

Before you show the keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager#showSoftInput( FOCUSED_VIEW, 0 );
```

Remove

```
TextView.setFocusable(false);
```

The `FOCUSED_VIEW` should be your `speed_edit_text`! Not the button.

Also make sure the following attributes for your `EditText` are set to enable multi line input:

```
android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:lines="8"
android:gravity="top|start"
android:minLines="6"
android:maxLines="10"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

The min, max and lines values are arbitrary number, but you can use that to set the domain of the height of the box.

[image: The result]

## About focus

The problem is your call to `TextView#setFocusable(false)`. When you set it to false you also lose focus to this element. So now when you display it again, Android doesn't know why to show the keyboard (because the `EditText` is not automagically focused when show it). Since you're hiding the view, you really don't need to make it unfocusable, it's `GONE` so it can't be focused.

- Request focus for the view you want to edit, when you are going to show the keyboard (`View#requestFocus`)
- Show the keyboard for the focused view
- When you're done, hide the keyboard
- Either clear focus or hide the element with focus (which is what you do)  (`View#clearFocus`)

## About the InputManager

You can show the keyboard with one of three values:

- 0: this is the [default when you click](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/3030c8e1db747c95a9d2692ddbc51d0013f9064d/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#5527) an `EditText`
- 1 (`SHOW_IMPLICIT`): this is not directly requested by the user
- 2 (`SHOW_FORCED`): force showing it, until the user "forces" it to close

You can hide the keyboard with one of three values:

- 0: this is the [default when you defocus](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/3030c8e1db747c95a9d2692ddbc51d0013f9064d/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#1202) an `EditText`
- 1: (`HIDE_IMPLICIT`): hide it if it was shown with `SHOW_IMPLICIT`
- 2: (`HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS`): hide it **unless** it was shown with `SHOW_FORCED`

However, you can force all you want. If an element is not focusable, you're not going to get automagic focus by showing the keyboard.

Comment: very well! thanks a lot. but as i use `textMultiLine` Done key disappear! do you suggest me to use Action mode for Done or do another. (pass texts from edit text to text view)

Comment: Yes. If you use IME Action, done is not replaced, it's hidden in the long press of the "enter" key. I would suggest you don't hide the edit button, but instead change the edit button into a "done" button.

Basically: if editing: edit button is done. If not editing: edit button is go to edit.

Comment: Ya. I prefer to have "Enter" key too. And will keep it on my key board... but how about finishing edit proccess? There must be sth for hiding soft key board. How can I do it, please give me your suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I would have either an extra button that you click to be done (save, done, whatever), with an `OnClickListener` that hides the keyboard, or change the graphic of the edit button and change the behaviour when you click it. The first thing is probably easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean bool =false;

editBTN= (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
 editBTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!bool)
        {
            speech_text_edit.setText(speech_text.getText().toString());
            bool = true; 
        }else
        {
            speech_text.setText(speech_text_edit.getText().toString());
            bool = false; 
        }


    }
 });
```

Comment: i do not want to limit line numbers. i want to place texts from the beginning of edit text generally.

Comment: I didn't get your question. You have 1 Textview, EditText, and Button, then on Button click you want to set text of Textview to EditText and then on the second click of button you again want to set Text of EditText to TextView. Is this Right?

Comment: semi yes/no. i mean from "second clicked" is repeat the strategy again - pass texts from text view to edit text  again. but there is no soft-keyboard  and pointer.

Comment: as TextView is used to show Text. If you click on editText you will get keyboard. I still not able to get what you are trying to say.

Comment: ok, i explain again. "Hello" is writen  in T.V. . editBTN is clicked. E.T. show "Hello" with keyboard and pointer. i edit it to "Hello world" . Done BTN is clicked, T.V. shows "Hello world" . its ok. now time i click editBTN again. E.T. shows  "Hello world" too, but soft-keyboard and pointer are not show/start.

Comment: i write down logcats.

Comment: I have  edited My answer. If there is any problem let me know.

Comment: i do ,but there is no change.